# Konacha adds 'iframe' to image urls that have the src attribute set programmatically

Tags: image, iframe, ember.js, integration-testing, client-side

I have just managed to get Konacha running for my client side integration tests.

Konacha runs the ember application in an iframe for testing. In my app, I create img elements programmatically based on user actions.  When I set the 'src' attribute the resulting url that is used to fetch the image file from the server has the '/iframe' part added to it like so:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3500/iframe/assets/regensberg/regensberg_1.jpg
```

Which gives a *404 (Not Found)*

The code does run correctly when I serve it from a regular rails development server

```
rails s
```

The correct url should read:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3500/assets/regensberg/regensberg_1.jpg
```

Any ideas why it is doing this an how to get around it?

*** Edit ***

Looking into the Konacha code I find the routes defined in *konacha/config/routes.rb*

```
Konacha::Engine.routes.draw do
  get '/iframe/*name' => 'specs#iframe', :format => false, :as => :iframe
  root :to => 'specs#parent'
  get '*path' => 'specs#parent', :format => false
end
```

We see that this request gets passed to the iframe method in the specs controller.

*konacha/app/controllers/konacha/specs*_ *controller.rb* shows us where the 404 message comes from.

```
module Konacha
  class SpecsController < ActionController::Base
    rescue_from Konacha::Spec::NotFound do
      render :text => "Not found", :status => 404
    end

    def parent
      @run_mode = params.fetch(:mode, Konacha.mode).to_s.inquiry
      @specs = Konacha::Spec.all(params[:path])
    end

    def iframe
      @spec = Konacha::Spec.find_by_name(params[:name])
      @stylesheets = Konacha::Engine.config.konacha.stylesheets
    end
  end
end
```

Looking into the model, we see where the *Spec::NotFound* comes from:

```
module Konacha
  class Spec
    class NotFound < StandardError
    end

    def self.all(path = nil)
      paths = Konacha.spec_paths
      paths = ENV["SPEC"].split(",") if ENV["SPEC"]
      paths = paths.map { |p| new(p) }
      if path.present?
        paths = paths.select { |s| s.path.starts_with?(path) }.presence or raise NotFound
      end
      paths
    end

    def self.find_by_name(name)
      all.find { |s| s.asset_name == name } or raise NotFound
    end

    attr_accessor :path

    def initialize(path)
      @path = path
    end

    def asset_name
      path.sub(/(\.js|\.coffee).*/, '')
    end
  end
end
```

With the above info, we see why we get the error message instead of the image file when we send the get request to the path that includes 'iframe'. So, why does the URL include 'iframe'?

Looking into the parent view code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Konacha Tests</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "konacha", :debug => false %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "mocha", "konacha/parent", :debug => false %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag("konacha/runner", :debug => false) if @run_mode.runner? %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% @specs.each do |spec| %>
      <%= content_tag :iframe, "", :src => iframe_path(spec.asset_name), :class => "test-context", "data-path" => spec.path %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

we see that the src for the iframe is the iframe path, which from the route above should be:

```
 0.0.0.0:3500/iframe/#{spec.assetName}
```

I set the img src paramter like this:

```
img.src = "assets/" + filename
```

the browser prepends "0.0.0.0:3500/iframe/" to this before making the request.  This seems to be causing the real trouble.  How to prevent the iframe from including this part in the base URL?

*** Finish Edit ***

By the way, can someone with a high-enough karma(>1500) create a Konacha tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assets/dir/filename.jpg` is a relative path; it is interpreted relative to the base URL of the page, which is `http://0.0.0.0:3500/iframe/`, producing `http://0.0.0.0:3500/iframe/assets/dir/filename.jpg`. You'll want to use the absolute path `/assets/dir/filename.jpg` instead, with a leading slash.